# What is the jutsu that ninjas use to appear/disappear instantly?

Tags: naruto

Some users of the jutsu are Kakashi, Gai, Genma, Kabuto, etc. It can often be seen when Anbu members are dismissed.

Comment: Can you expand your question a little bit? like add references to manga/anime(where you see it happen)

Comment: iKlsR has given the correct answer. 
Kakashi uses that technique during Chunnin exam Preliminary round and Gai uses it to appear infront of Rock Lee to punish him for using a forbidden move against Sasuke.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most common one I know of and I think you are talking about is the [Body Flicker Technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Body_Flicker_Technique) (also known as Teleportation Jutsu, or *Shunshin no Jutsu*).

[image: Jiraiya vanishes in a puff of smoke]

> The Body Flicker Technique is a high-speed movement technique,
>   allowing a ninja to move short to long distances at an almost
>   untraceable speed.[<sup>*</sup>](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Body_Flicker_Technique#cite_note-Chapter_395-1)
>
> To an observer, it appears as if the user has
>   teleported. A puff of smoke is ***occasionally*** used to disguise the
>   user's movements. It is accomplished by using chakra to temporarily
>   vitalise the body and move at extreme speeds. The amount of chakra
>   required depends on the overall distance and elevation between the
>   user and the intended destination.

Answer (score 2):

It could also be a shadow clone.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that it'd be a Shadow Clone. Do you have anything that could back up your opinion?

Comment: Meh. There is no jutsu that make one appear/disappear. It's only shadow clones that disappear. I remember an episode where naruto had to master his wind nature energy, and talked with asuma sensei. It was a shadow clone who was talking with azuma, when they were done talking, naruto undid the shadow clone and azuma mentioned it was a shadow clone. it was episode 56, minute 7:35.